# Javascript canvas.toDataUrl() Send picture to an <img> element in a new window

Tags: javascript, canvas

What am I doing wrong here?

Im trying to save a canvas drawing by having it open a new window and displaying .png in an img element that is positioned on the page with css.

From there you will have the option to download it or share it.

I have this so far, but the img src is not being populated with the toDataUrl();

```
function saveDrawing() {
    var url = canvas.toDataURL(); 
    window.open('saveimage.php'); 
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder");  
    placeholder.src = url;  
}
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementById("placeholder");` is not looking for that ID in the newly opened window, but in the current one.
All you have to do is reference the newly created window's document:

```
function saveDrawing() {
    var url = canvas.toDataURL(); 
    w = window.open('saveimage.php'); 
    w.onload = function(){
        var placeholder = w.document.getElementById("placeholder");  
        placeholder.src = url;
    };  
}
```

This might have mistakes, the idea is that you store a reference to the new window in `w`, and then when it's loaded, access it's DOM to modify the image src

Comment: There's no restriction on access to other windows open from the same domain, as appears to be the case here.

Comment: True, I don't know why I thought it was otherwise

Comment: It is on the same domain. Do I have to set the focus to the opened window or something?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect this